# Django Record Locking and Atomic Transactions

Tags: python, django, postgresql, mariadb

I am trying to implement some critical updates in a project that I'm doing.
In summary, I need to take information from a work file which does some further processing and then updates it to a final file. This information comes from different sources so it is best to do it on the middle file which then writes it to the final file.

My problem is that some of the detail lines data is getting lost among the way. I have duplicated this problem in the below files to eliminate any crud. Simply run the functions in a manage.py shell. This shows up both in Mariadb as well as Postgresql.

Is there a better way to achiever this instead of a workaround?

The models.py:

```
import random
from decimal import Decimal

from django.db import models, transaction


class Head(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    h1_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")

    def update(self):
        tmp1 = Tmp1Head()
        tmp1.name = self.h1_text
        tmp1.save()
        for line in self.head_lines.all():
            tl1 = Tmp1Line()
            tl1.head = tmp1
            tl1.data_text = line.data_text
            tl1.t1_data = line.t1_data
            tl1.t2_data = Decimal(random.random())
            tl1.save()

        with transaction.atomic():
            transaction.on_commit(tmp1.update)

        tmp1.delete()  # All fine - remove this work transaction.
        return True


class Line(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Head, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='head_lines')
    data_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    t1_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)


class Tmp1Head(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")

    def update(self):
        tmp2 = Tmp2Head()
        tmp2.name = self.name
        tmp2.save()
        for line in self.tmp1_lines.all():
            tl2 = Tmp2Line()
            tl2.head = tmp2
            tl2.data_summary = line.data_text
            tl2.final_data = line.t1_data * line.t2_data
            tl2.save()


class Tmp1Line(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Tmp1Head, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tmp1_lines')
    data_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    t1_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    t2_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)


class Tmp2Head(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")


class Tmp2Line(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Tmp2Head, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tmp2_lines')
    data_summary = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    final_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

The views.py

```
from .models import *


def populate():
    Head.objects.all().delete()
    Tmp1Head.objects.all().delete()
    Tmp2Head.objects.all().delete()

    head = Head.objects.create(name="test", h1_text="test text")
    for tmp in range(1, 5):
        Line.objects.create(head=head,
                            data_text=f"data line:{tmp}",
                            t1_data=tmp)


def test1(): # all fine but no locking.
    batch = Head.objects.first()
    batch.update()


def test2():  # record locking but the data lines get lost in the final table.
    with transaction.atomic():
        batch = Head.objects.select_for_update().first()
        batch.update()


def test3():  # record locking, no data lost, but the temp data is not removed.
    """
    Same as test 2 but remove the below line from update function in the Head model.
        tmp1.delete()  # All fine - remove this work transaction.
    """
    with transaction.atomic():
        batch = Head.objects.select_for_update().first()
        batch.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to solve this I took away the save points and now all seems okay.
It should be safe as only the procedure should have access to the interim files.

I removed this from the models.py:

```
# with transaction.atomic():
# transaction.on_commit(tmp1.update)
tmp1.update()
```